# Properties of matrix Lie groups which are not shared by general Lie groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, lie-groups

I am reading Brian Hall's book 'Lie groups, Lie algberas, and Representations' and on p52, corollary 2.34 reads : " Every continuous homomorphism between two matrix Lie groups is smooth."

I am wondering if this is true for general Lie groups. If not, please provide a counterexample.

What are all the properties that hold good for matrix Lie groups (and their representations) but not for general Lie groups ? It would be very helpful for me to have a list.

Comment: The result is true in general: every continuous homomorphism between Lie groups is automatically smooth.  With regards to your general question, you might find this mathoverflow thread useful: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/81610/is-an-identity-that-is-true-for-matrix-lie-groups-true-for-all-lie-groups